# Error with pre-trained Mask R-CNN Inception ResNet V2 1024x1024 model using TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection-api, mask-rcnn

I am attempting to fine-tune a pre-trained Mask R-CNN Inception ResNet V2 1024x1024 model using the TensorFlow Object Detection API for a custom task. I have downloaded the model from this [location](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/mask_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_1024x1024_coco17_gpu-8.tar.gz).

I have created a pipeline configuration for this model, specifying my training and evaluation TFRecord datasets and the path to the downloaded checkpoint as the fine_tune_checkpoint.

However, when I run the model_main_tf2.py script to initiate the training, I encounter an error stating that some variables from the checkpoint are missing in the model. The error is as follows:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/content/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 114, in <module> tf.compat.v1.app.run() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 36, in run _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 308, in run _run_main(main, args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 254, in _run_main sys.exit(main(argv)) File "/content/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 105, in main model_lib_v2.train_loop( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 605, in train_loop load_fine_tune_checkpoint( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 398, in load_fine_tune_checkpoint raise ValueError('Checkpoint version should be V2') ValueError: Checkpoint version should be V2`

This error suggests that there is a mismatch between the model architecture defined in my pipeline and the architecture of the pre-trained model. However, as far as I can see, my pipeline configuration is correctly set up for the Mask R-CNN Inception ResNet V2 1024x1024 model.

Furthermore, I have inspected the checkpoint file using the inspect_checkpoint.py script and it seems to include all the variables expected for this model. The downloaded checkpoint files include **ckpt-0.index**, **ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001**, and **checkpoint**.

I am running this on Google Colab with TensorFlow version 2.12.0 and Python version 3.10.0. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or solutions to this problem.

### To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Download the pre-trained Mask R-CNN Inception ResNet V2 1024x1024 model from the TensorFlow Model Zoo.
2. Set up a custom training pipeline configuration, specifying the path to the downloaded checkpoint in the fine_tune_checkpoint field.
3. Run the model training script (model_main_tf2.py).
4. The error appears indicating some variables from the checkpoint are not found in the model.

### Expected behavior

I expect the model training to begin by loading weights from the specified pre-trained model. The error seems to suggest a mismatch between the model architecture defined in my pipeline and the architecture of the pre-trained model. Still, my pipeline configuration appears to be correctly set up for the Mask R-CNN Inception ResNet V2 1024x1024 model.

### Additional context

Upon inspecting the checkpoint file with inspect_checkpoint.py, it does appear to contain all the expected variables for a Mask R-CNN Inception ResNet V2 1024x1024 model. I also confirmed that the downloaded files include ckpt-0.index, ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001, and checkpoint. Yet, the issue persists. Any guidance or solutions to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

I have attached my pipeline.config file below:
[pipeline.txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/files/11712885/pipeline.txt)
[image]
[image]

### System information

- OS Platform and Distribution: Google Colab
- TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): source
- TensorFlow version: 2.12.0
- Python version: 3.10.0
- GPU model and memory: A100; 40GB

Comment: sorry, this site is not for [bug reports](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/11016). please [edit] your question to bring it in line with [ask], or close it and work with the [bug report](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/11016) you already filed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this following flag to train_config: section below your fine_tune_checkpoint: entry

fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"

Also note there seems to be an open issue with this model -

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9546

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9527 this is the actual issue with M-RCNN 1024x1024 on Tensorflow . Please update with a response if you found a solution.